# Dash in date format and get method

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have asp (classic) script and within javascript code. From database I get date in format yyyy-mm-dd (2010-10-14) and save in variable. Then, I pass this variable to javascript method:

```
Response.Write("&#60;a href='Javascript: PassDate("&OurDate&","&Val1&","&Val2&");'>Pass&#60;/a>")
```

This method code is:

```
function PassDate(OurDate, Val1, Val2)
{
    window.open("newsite.asp?date="+OurDate+"&val1="+Val1+"&val2="+Val2"); 

}
```

When I try get date on new site (newsite.asp) by Request.QueryString("date"), I get calculate value 1996 (2010-10-14 = 1986), instead date '2010-10-14'.
I try various ways to solve this problem, but it still calculate value.
For example, I try replace "-" for ".", but I get error about missing ")".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use commas instead of dashes. That way, each part will be seen as a separate argument to the JavaScript function.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  But how can I get all arguments - when I try: Response.Write(Request.QueryString("date")) I get only year: 2010?

Comment: Surround it in square brackets, for example, [2010] or [2010,10,14] -- that way it will be seen as one argument (an array) to JavaScript (OurDate[0], OurDate[1], ...).

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have to only make: Replace(Request.QueryString("date"),",","-") and get date with dashes. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered saving the date using the javascript date object and then passing that to your method?
My javascript is a little rusty, but I believe it would be something like the following:

```
var dateParts = split(OurDate, "-");
var myDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1], dateParts[2]);
```